# Window phone: how to add new phone page

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm new to window phone.

I add new buttons dynamicly,then click the button lead to a new phone page.As you can add as many buttons as you want theoretically,so you can add that many new pages，but is it impossible to add new pages directly in development mode?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: May I ask why would you want to do that?

Comment: oh, i'm new i like to know new things

Comment: It is possible but that would negate the whole purpose of using the power of xaml.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot create a new xaml page altogether, but can create a single xaml page and load it with different xaml each time you need it customized. Do let me know if I am wrong, even I might get a bit of knowledge here ;)